# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' error when saving image to mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem on my codes pertaining to saving image to mysql database. Can someone help me please?

```
Sub newstud()
    If cbCard.Checked = True Then
        card = "COMPLETE"
    End If
    If cbBirthCert.Checked = True Then
        birthcert = "COMPLETE"
    End If
    If cbForm.Checked = True Then
        form = "COMPLETE"
    End If
    If cbGMoral.Checked = True Then
        gmoral = "COMPLETE"
    End If

    If picStr = vbNullString Then
        picImage.Image.Save(".png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        picStr = Application.StartupPath + (".\noimage.png")
    End If


    IMG = (Nothing)
    IMG = Image.FromFile(picStr)

    MyStream = New MemoryStream
    IMG.Save(MyStream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
    con.Open()
    Try
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into tbregistration(StudName,StudBday,StudGender,Address,DadName,DadBday,DadOccupation,MomName,MomBday,MomOccupation,Contact,LastSchool,Card,Form137,BirthCertificate,GoodMoral,Image)values('" & txtStudName.Text & "','" & dtpBirthday.Text & "','" & cmbGender.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtDadName.Text & "','" & dtpDadBday.Text & "','" & txtDadOccu.Text & "','" & txtMomName.Text & "','" & dtpMomBday.Text & "','" & txtMomOccu.Text & "','" & txtContact.Text & "','" & txtLastSchool.Text & "','" & card & "','" & form & "','" & birthcert & "','" & gmoral & "',@img,'"")", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", MySqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = MyStream.GetBuffer
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()

        MyStream.Dispose()
        MyStream = Nothing
        MsgBox("Admission done successfully", , "Admission")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

That's the code for my save button

```
Dim imgdlg As FileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    imgdlg.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif;*.png"


If imgdlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    picStr = imgdlg.FileName
Else
    picStr = ""
    Exit Sub

End If

picImage.Image = Drawing.Image.FromFile(picStr)
```

And this is for the browse image button. Please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Please specify exactly what line generates the error message.

Comment: it shows in the cmd.ExecutNonQuery line

Comment: The first thing to do would be to write your SQL properly and use parameters for ALL values and not just that one.  I suspect that you've written your SQL incorrectly but it's hard to read like that.  Also, it would be more appropriate to call `ToArray` on your `MemoryStream` than `GetBuffer`.  Read the documentation for the `GetBuffer` method and you'll see why.

Comment: It's working in msaccess database but when i am converting it into mysql database it shows that error

Comment: If you're too lazy to write your VB code properly then I'm not inclined to spend any more of my time to try to help. If you are prepared to write your VB code properly then we can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to write:

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into tbregistration(StudName,StudBday,StudGender,Address,DadName,DadBday,DadOccupation,MomName,MomBday,MomOccupation,Contact,LastSchool,Card,Form137,BirthCertificate,GoodMoral,Image)values('" & txtStudName.Text & "','" & dtpBirthday.Text & "','" & cmbGender.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtDadName.Text & "','" & dtpDadBday.Text & "','" & txtDadOccu.Text & "','" & txtMomName.Text & "','" & dtpMomBday.Text & "','" & txtMomOccu.Text & "','" & txtContact.Text & "','" & txtLastSchool.Text & "','" & card & "','" & form & "','" & birthcert & "','" & gmoral & "',@img,'"")", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = MyStream.GetBuffer
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Note the change in line 2 from `MySqlDbType` to `SqlDbType`

Comment: I am using mysql not sql

Comment: What namespace is it in? Is it a NuGet package?

Comment: It's Connector/Net, i.e. the ADO.NET provider from MySQL.  The types mimic those of SqlClient and are members of the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace.

Comment: Other than just copy pasting into visual studio and checking for compiler errors, there isn't much help anyone can give if you don't tell us _exactly_ what is wrong. What error is being thrown where? Is it runtime or compile-time? What is the debug information that is included when the error is thrown?

Comment: @westonesupermare yes

Comment: When i run the code it doesn't get any errors but upon saving the image it gives the error i put on the title